# clone the old flutter project and it is not working, any thoughts how to fix this

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I have cloned this project https://github.com/2d-inc/developer_quest
and when I try to run the project on android then get the following error

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.15.0-42.0.dev.
```

Because test >=1.16.0-nullsafety <1.16.0-nullsafety.8 requires SDK version >=2.10.0-0 <2.12.0 and test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.8 <1.16.0-nullsafety.18 depends on typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0, test >=1.16.0-nullsafety <1.16.0-nullsafety.18 requires typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0.
And because test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.18 <1.16.0-nullsafety.19 depends on test_api 0.2.19-nullsafety.7 and test >=1.3.0 <1.12.0 depends on boolean_selector ^1.0.0, test >=1.3.0 <1.12.0-∞ or >=1.16.0-nullsafety <1.16.0-nullsafety.19 requires typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0 or test_api 0.2.19-nullsafety.7 or boolean_selector ^1.0.0.
And because test >=1.12.0 <1.13.0 depends on test_api 0.2.14 and test >=1.13.0 <1.14.5 depends on test_api 0.2.15, test >=1.3.0 <1.14.5-∞ or >=1.16.0-nullsafety <1.16.0-nullsafety.19 requires typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0 or test_api 0.2.14 or 0.2.15 or 0.2.19-nullsafety.7 or boolean_selector ^1.0.0.
And because test >=1.14.5 <1.15.0 depends on test_api 0.2.16 and test >=1.15.0 <1.15.3 depends on test_api 0.2.17, test >=1.3.0 <1.15.3-∞ or >=1.16.0-nullsafety <1.16.0-nullsafety.19 requires typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0 or test_api 0.2.14 or 0.2.15 or 0.2.16 or 0.2.17 or 0.2.19-nullsafety.7 or boolean_selector ^1.0.0.
And because test >=1.15.3 <1.15.5 depends on test_api 0.2.18 and test >=1.15.5 <1.16.0-nullsafety depends on test_api 0.2.18+1, test >=1.3.0 <1.16.0-nullsafety.19 requires typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0 or test_api 0.2.14 or 0.2.15 or 0.2.16 or 0.2.17 or 0.2.18 or 0.2.18+1 or 0.2.19-nullsafety.7 or boolean_selector ^1.0.0.
And because test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.19 <1.16.6 depends on test_api 0.2.19 and every version of flutter_driver from sdk depends on boolean_selector 2.1.0, if test >=1.3.0 <1.16.6 and flutter_driver any from sdk then test_api 0.2.14 or 0.2.15 or 0.2.16 or 0.2.17 or 0.2.18 or 0.2.18+1 or 0.2.19-nullsafety.7 or 0.2.19 or typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0.
And because every version of flutter_driver from sdk depends on test_api 0.4.3 and every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on typed_data 1.3.0, one of flutter_test any from sdk or test >=1.3.0 <1.16.6 or flutter_driver any from sdk must be false.
And because test >=1.16.6 depends on webkit_inspection_protocol ^1.0.0 which depends on logging ^1.0.0, if flutter_test any from sdk and flutter_driver any from sdk and test >=1.3.0 then logging ^1.0.0.
And because dev_rpg depends on both flutter_test any from sdk and flutter_driver any from sdk, test >=1.3.0 requires logging ^1.0.0.
So, because dev_rpg depends on both logging ^0.11.3+2 and test ^1.6.1, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in developer_quest...
pub get failed (1; So, because dev_rpg depends on both logging ^0.11.3+2 and test ^1.6.1, version solving failed.)

and here is my pubspec.yaml file code

```
    name: dev_rpg
description: Become a tech lead, slay bugs, and don't get fired.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# Read more about versioning at semver.org.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  # For Google I/O we are being very specific about pinning to specific branch revision.
  # This is flutter commit hash b593f5167bce84fb3cad5c258477bf3abc1b14eb, tagged
  # as Flutter version 1.5.4.
  sdk: ">=2.3.0-dev.0.1 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: any
  provider: ^2.0.0

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  flare_flutter: ^1.8.3
  auto_size_text: ^1.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_driver:
    sdk: flutter
  logging: ^0.11.3+2
  git: ^0.5.1+1
  t_stats: ^2.0.0
  test: ^1.6.1


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/style_sphinx/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/images/2.0x/
    - assets/images/3.0x/
    - assets/flare/
    - assets/docs/code_chomper_alpha.dart
    - assets/docs/code_chomper_beta.dart

  fonts:
      - family: SpaceMonoRegular
        fonts:
          - asset: assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf
      - family: SpaceMonoBold
        fonts:
          - asset: assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Bold.ttf
      - family: RobotoCondensedBold
        fonts:
          - asset: assets/fonts/RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf
      - family: RobotoRegular
        fonts:
          - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
      - family: MontserratMedium
        fonts:
          - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.otf
      - family: MontserratRegular
        fonts:
          - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.otf
      - family: MontserratBold
        fonts:
          - asset: assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.otf
```

I have tried upgrading

````dart
flutter channel dev 
flutter create .  ```
````

Comment: you should follow the developer's guide for converting the project to the flutter 2.

Answer (score 1):

Well as the errors say, the project has some dependencies that are not met by the version of flutter you have (because of the libraries that are shipped with flutter itself).

The `pubspec.yaml` of the project says it is supposed to work with flutter version  `1.5.4.` so, If you want to run that project you would need to download that compatible flutter sdk

Comment: I installed the flutter 1.5.4 now through fvm now and still no luck . 
now I get the dart version error and gradle build error.

Comment: Try `  sdk: ">=2.3.0 <3.0.0"` Using a less specific dart version. If that fails could you update the question with the new error logs?

Comment: got this error while using the ` sdk: ">=2.3.0 <3.0.0"`
```../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-2.0.1+1/lib/src/provider.dart:179:54: Error: 'Name' isn't a type.
        ? context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<Name>(type) as _Provider<T```